# What to do when waiting for a event to finish

Tags: c, multithreading, events

gcc 4.4.3 c89

I have a event loop that runs in a separate thread.

My design is like this below, just sample code to help explain.

I need to somehow wait for the initialization to complete before I can make a call to the get_device_params.

I did put a usleep for 3 seconds just before the call to the get_device_params, but I don't really want to block.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

```
void* process_events(void *data)
{
    switch(event_type)
    {
        case EVT_INITIALIZED:
            /* Device is now initialized */    
        break;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    /* Create and start thread and process incoming events */
    process_events();

    /* Initialize device */
    initialize_device(); 

    /* Get device parameters */
    /* However, I cannot run this code until initialization is complete */
    get_device_params();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you calling get_device_params() in the event loop on the EVT_INITIALIZED event?

Comment: What platform does it run on?

Comment: @Paul. There is some extra processing that has to be done. So cannot call from the EVT_INITIALIZED event.

Comment: @Tadeusz. Running on Ubuntu Linux

Comment: Your question isn't entirely clear - if you don't want to block, what useful work *do* you want to do while you're waiting for initialisation to complete?

Comment: @Caf, you are right. What was I thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to somehow wait for the initialization to complete before I can make a call to the get_device_params.

Since you apparently have some sort of a [FSM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) inside the `process_events()`, and it why ever runs in a separate thread, you shouldn't do anything from the main thread with the device.

In other words, logically, call to the `get_device_params();` should be placed inside the FSM, on the event that the device is initialized `EVT_INITIALIZED` which I presume is triggered by the `initialize_device()`.

Alternatively, you can create second FSM (possibly in another thread) and let the `process_events()` (the first FSM) after it has finished its own processing, forward the `EVT_INITIALIZED` event to the second FSM. (Or `initialize_device()` could send the event to the both FSMs simultaneously.)

To me it seems (from the scarce code you have posted) that your problem is that you try to mix sequential code with an event based one. Rule of thumb: in event/FSM based application all code should run inside the FSM, being triggered by an event; there should be no code which may run on its own outside of the FSM.

Answer (score 4):

If this separate thread is a POSIX thread (i.e. you're on a typical UNIX platform), then you can use pthread conditional variables.

You call [`pthread_cond_wait()`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html) in the waiting thread. When the init thread finishes its work, you call [`pthread_cond_signal()`](http://opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_cond_signal.html). In my opinion that's a canonical way to wait for initialization in another thread.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, I would probably use a barrier.  In main you can call pthread_barrier_init, indicating that you have 2 threads.  Then, in main call pthread_barrier_wait, to wait on the barrier you initialized, after calling your device initialization function.  Finally, in the device thread, after you initialize your device, you can call pthread_barrier_wait on the same barrier and when both threads are waiting, the barrier will have been satisfied, so both threads will continue.  I find barriers easier to use than condition variables sometime, but I'm sure that's an issue of preference.